# View split on top/bottom in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: shortcut-keys, window

In Ubuntu 22.04 one can press `super`+`left`/`right` to snap windows to the left/right side of the screen. I want to do the same but with `up` and `down` which right now maximaze/umaximaze windows. Is this possible in Ubuntu 22.04?

I found the [ShellTile](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/657/shelltile/) extension for this but it is not compatible with Ubuntu 22.04.

Comment: I have the same problem with [`Put Windows`](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/39/put-windows/).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with `WinTile` and `Put Windows`. I end up using different extensions with similar features for 22.04 such as
[`Tiling Assistant`](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/3733/tiling-assistant/) ([GitHub](https://github.com/Leleat/Tiling-Assistant/wiki/Active-Window-Hint)) or [`Quarter Windows`](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/4857/quarter-windows/).

This is my current setting of `Tiling Assistant` for my Ubuntu `22.04.04`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a feature planned to be added to Ubuntu Budgie (23.04) based on the [Window Shuffler](https://github.com/UbuntuBudgie/window-shuffler) repo. I have not tried it myself but according to [this](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2023/01/test-ubuntu-budgie-window-snapping) article users of 22.04 LTS and 22.10 can install/test it by adding the repository:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntubudgie-dev/budgie-extras-daily
sudo apt upgrade
```